# Using a button to communicate between Main and Renderer

Tags: reactjs, electron, ipc

I learned about leveraging `Main.js` as a way to avoid some browser limitations in Electron today. I want to do something simple: When someone presses on a button, I want to send a `"ping"` to `Main`. I then want `Main` to send a `"pong"` back, and print that in `console`.

For the recond, I need to set `nodeIntegration` to false. Here is what I have so far:

```
//preload.js
window.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer

//Main.js
const electron = require('electron');
const ipc = electron.ipcMain;
function createWindow(){
    // set preload and BrowserWindow with nodeIntegration: false
}
ipc.on('request-mainprocess-action', function(event, data) {
    console.log("PING RECEIVED: " + data)
    event.sender.send('mainprocess-response', "PONG!");
})

//MyReactComponent.js
submit() { // submit button handler
    window.ipcRenderer.send('request-mainprocess-action', "PING!");

    window.ipcRenderer.on('mainprocess-response', (event, arg) => {
        console.log(arg);
    })
}
```

However, when I click on the submit button, nothing happens. Can someone point me out to what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main

```
ipc.on('request-mainprocess-action', function(event, data) {
    console.log("PING RECEIVED: " + data)
    // event.sender.send('mainprocess-response', "PONG!");
    event.reply('mainprocess-response', 'PONG!');
})
```

Or

```
ipc.on('request-mainprocess-action', function(event, data) {
    console.log("PING RECEIVED: " + data)
    // event.sender.send('mainprocess-response', "PONG!");
    win.webContents.send('mainprocess-response', "PONG!");
})
```